# What is the difference between ava and ava-tf

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ava

I found that there are two packages `ava` and `ava-tf`.

But I didn't find and description how they differ.

Answer (score 2):

They are the same package, the valid and better one to use is ava. You can see this on the npm entry for ava-tf, where the install instructions point to the ava package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ava-tf

```
$ npm install --global ava
$ ava --init
```

Comment: Yea, `ava-tf` looks like some sort of fork. Outdated, too.